# Google Sheets: Counting X where Y from column of uniques

Tags: google-sheets, unique, matching

I have no idea how to do this.  I could do this in other programs but no idea here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rXTCfG9wbFqPUtl9w8h4WcSolWEowxFk94O3nY6Ib30/

This is a list of characters in a game, matching accounts.  Column B is the accountname.  Column E is a rank the characters are given based on things.  Column O is a list of unique accountnames.  Objective is to populate Column P with a list of unique accountnames that are of rank Citizen.  The logic is basically:

```
for( columnO )
{
if( columnO.columnE == "Citizen" )
 {
  columnP();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!B3:B, Sheet1!E3:E = "Citizen"))`

***Edit***

Changed formula based on comments from @Victor Sheckels

The formula looks for all of the account names in column B that correspond to the rank "Citizen" in column E, and then uses `UNIQUE()` to return on only the unique values.

[image]

Comment: Does not work because Ox does not correspond to Ex.

Inelegant solution: create dummy columnW, parse it for uniques.


     =if(E3="Citizen",B3,"")
     =UNIQUE(W3:W)

Comment: One more thing, when you're submitting spreadsheet just have them in black and white. All the colours you were using make it quite difficult to read and parse the cells.